# Transforming a variable from string to numeric

Tags: stata

I'm trying to convert a binary variable from a string (e.g. "Male" or "Female") into binary (0 and 1). I tried with the following:

```
replace q1=1 if q1=="Female"
```

but I get the following error: `type mismatch`. What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Please note that I do not want to create a new variable, but only to conditionally replace values in the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution: turn it into a number of a type string and use the `destring` command.

```
replace q1="1" if q1=="Female"
destring q1, replace
```

Comment: This isn't the best solution. Having value labels is a good idea and sometimes even  essential. How is the researcher or the reader supposed to know that 1 means Female. See other replies.

Comment: you are exactly right! what I did was just that I just wrote something like `label var1 "female=1"`. I saw your comment only after i solved the problem, but since it does seem more elegant, i will try it next time.

Comment: update: i added value labels separately from variable labels

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, unfortunately. You HAVE to create a new variable.
The problem is that `q1` is currently of string type. So it cannot store numerical data as such.

Why don't you just create a new variable, and "drop" the old one?

```
encode q1, gen(q1b)
drop q1
ren q1b q1
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! it's because I have multiple gender variables and i would like to preserve the order. by any chance, do you know how to move columns left and right?

Comment: You can use the command "order". That will sort variables in the order you provide, leaving all unnamed for last. Say you have the following variable list: a b c d e, but you want "e and d" to be first, you would do  "order e d" this will leave the variables as e d a b c

Comment: You can store numeric characters in strings, so that using `"1"` as a replacement would have been legal (but not helpful).

Comment: `encode` by default will create integers 1 up with value labels formed from the strings supplied. As in the question, for statistical purposes people usually prefer indicators (often called dummy variables) with values 0 and 1. You can get that with `encode` by defining the value labels explicitly ahead of the `encode`. https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099 also gives a detailed discussion.